# Is while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) a endless loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

The issue is **while((message = reader.readLine()) != null)** loop doesn't end. I mean; lets say client didn't send anything, so while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) would be false and it should finish the loop, doesn't it ?
A few times later, the client wants to send a message but the loop was finished. How could the server start the loop again and get the message?

It works like when(a message was sent run the code)

This is my server code...

public class SimpleChatServer {

```
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

public static void main(String[] args){
    new SimpleChatServer().go();
}

public void go(){
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
    try{
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while(true){
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("got a connection");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable{
    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket soc;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket){
        try{
            soc = clientSocket;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Listener Established!");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("We couldn't make a connection!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        String message;
        try{
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Reader:" + message);
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void tellEveryone(String message){
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        try{
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

and This is my client code:

```
public class SimpleChatClient {
JTextArea incoming;
JTextField outgoing;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Socket soc;

public static void main(String[] args){
    SimpleChatClient client = new SimpleChatClient();
    client.go();
}

public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    outgoing = new JTextField(20);
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new sendButtonListener());
    mainPanel.add(scroller);
    mainPanel.add(outgoing);
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);
    setUpNetworking();

    Thread readerThread = new Thread(new incomingReader());
    readerThread.start();


    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void setUpNetworking(){
    try{
        soc = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
        writer = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Networking established!");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("We couldn't connect the server!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class sendButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
            String message = outgoing.getText();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        }catch(Exception Ex){
            Ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        outgoing.setText("");
        outgoing.requestFocus();
    }
}

public class incomingReader implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        String message;
        try{
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("read:" + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not an infinite loop.

Basically, what it's doing is that it keeps on reading until it detects that there is no input.

Comment: `while((message = reader.readLine()) != null)` will continue to loop until `readLine()` returns `null`, which the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--), says happens when *"the end of the stream has been reached"*. Which means that when reading from a socket, the loop will end when the socket is **closed by the remote party**.

Comment: reader.readLine() will return null when the loop ends

Comment: But why isn't ``System.out.println("read:" + message);`` printed more times if ``while`` is running all the time as ``true``?